# xml <! > element

Tags: xml

is there any connection between notation of CDATA sections and internal DTD definition?
i mean both of these things are closed in that `<! >` element... so i wondered if there is any special meaning for this kind of element or is it just made exception considered as standard for defining CDATA and DTD ?

if you can't understand what's on my mind simply said my question is "what is the function of `<! >` element in general? (if there is some)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a markup declaration. It is meant for the XML parser to interpret rather than be considered as part of the data of the XML document.

Comment: but the parser won't let it pass if you leave it void.?. so if there is nothing in it that could be somehow interpreted it's considered as xml data and thus not valid... ? ?

Comment: I'm not sure what the parser would do if the proc instr was invalid/void. It could throw an exception or ignore it. Probably would depend on which parser was being used.

Comment: -1, terminology quibble: it's `<?` which introduces processing instructions (which are unstandardised instructions to the application); `<!` introduces 'markup declarations', which are (as you say) standardised instructions to the parser

Answer (score 3):

The `<!` sequence opens *markup declarations*.  It's distinct from *processing instructions*, which start with `<?`.

The [XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#dt-markupdecl) defines a class of 'markup declarations', but doesn't call out the `<!` syntax specifically (though the SGML spec, which preceded it, named this pair of characters *markup declaration open*).  Those declarations are things you'd find inside a DTD, but the same characters introduce CDATA marked sections and comments.

What unites these is that they're instructions to the XML *parser*: 'skip this' (a comment), 'don't parse this' (a CDATA section), 'understand this' (a DTD).

That's different from a *processing instruction* `<?`, which is an instruction to the *application* which is ultimately processing the parsed XML.  Processing instructions can be just about anything -- they're effectively a 'back door' to the document and are generally application-specific -- but common ones are `<?newpage?>` or possibly `<?issueref "fixed in 123"?>`.

Answer (score 0):

Text defined in CDATA section in an xml document is not parsed by the xml processor.

A Document Type Definition (DTD) defines the legal building blocks of an XML document. It defines the document structure with a list of legal elements and attributes.

A DTD can be declared inline inside an XML document, or as an external reference.